# Office Communicator: Remove Contact from Conversation with VBA

Tags: automation, vba, office-communicator-2007

The [IMessengerConversationWnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/bb758818%28v=office.12%29.aspx) interface exposes the `AddContact` method which allows us to add a contact to the conversation.

However I do not see a method for removing a contact from the conversation. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of iMessenger are you using? [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/bb758812%28v=office.12%29.aspx) from MS shows info for different interfaces, including the AddContact method you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Via the Communicator API this is simply not currently possible. Sorry!